# SQL Server(T-sql) Update table from botom to top

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, lag, lead

im trying to update table temp(F4) result from bottom to top.
Is it while-loop every row and update can be order by?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Which column are you updating? What are you updating it to? What's the update critera? Please post a sample result for this table

Comment: There is no **intrinsic** meaning to the concepts of **_top/bottom of a database table_**. A table is a storage of information and you set its only order upon retrieval (which may take following any legal rule for one or more fields). There are "tools" (i.e. keys) that can be defined on behalf of data extraction efficiency, and these keys can be used as part of the sorting paradigm.

Comment: Looks like you are ordering by `row` and you want to update F4 to the next non zero value? Is that correct?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming `ROW` is a positive integer then you can use ([demo](http://rextester.com/OFF1138))

```
WITH T1 AS
(
SELECT *, 
       MIN(CASE WHEN F4 <> 0 THEN CONCAT(FORMAT([ROW],'D10'),[F4]) END) 
         OVER (ORDER BY [ROW] ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS M
FROM temp

)
SELECT *, 
       CAST(SUBSTRING(M,11,11) AS INT) AS val
FROM T1
ORDER BY [ROW]
```

If you want to update `F4` you can use

```
WITH T1 AS
(
SELECT *, 
      MIN(CASE WHEN F4 <> 0 THEN CONCAT(FORMAT([ROW],'D10'),[F4]) END) 
           OVER (ORDER BY [ROW] ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS M
FROM temp

)
UPDATE T1
SET F4 = COALESCE(SUBSTRING(M,11,11),0);
```

Comment: Hi @Martin, Thanks for replying. This is what I need. Not really familiar with this statement (CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING).

Comment: This question lacks critical clarity, therefore it is impossible to provide an exact answer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - it is possible to infer the spec from the desired result and the comment above "This is what I need" shows the inferrence was correct